# Whats a good Workflow solution for an existing Wicket Web application?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, workflow, wicket

I' writing a web application with Wicket 1.4.X, Hibernate 3.6, and Spring 2.5.6.

I have some objects
For Example:

- Person

  - name
  - SSN
  - positon
  - etc....

now some fields are not editable. say `SSN`, however other fields like `position`, are only editable for managers. If a supervisor makes the change, it gets forwarded on to a manager for approval.  I have a homegrown system currently in place for part of this. However, it seems to me that an actual workflow system would allow me to collect all of the rules into one nice convenient location rather than having them scattered around my code.

I'm looking for a system that is:

- Simple
- Integrates well with the technologies I'm already using
- Doesn't require a separate server
  (the app is internal I don't need "on-the-fly" rules changes)

I keep coming across references to [jBPM](http://www.jboss.org/jbpm) having no "real" experience with workflows it looks like the easiest/most efficient route to install it is by installing [Drools](http://www.jboss.org/drools). The [Drools and jBPM integration Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.3.0.Final/droolsjbpm-integration-docs/html/index.html) even talks about Spring integration. 
However, the documentation felt sparse and I didn't completely understand what I was looking at.  Before I start down the (what I assume to be long) road of Drools/jBPM I wanted to get a community consensus from people smarter then me on the subject of workflows.

**UPDATE:**

I talked with my boss about this issue. We currently have another "in-house" application. (currently maintained by external contractors) that's using Stellent, now known as
[Oracle Universal Content Management](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/content-management/059244.html) with [Oracle BPM](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/bpm/index.html).  While I should probably learn these technologies since I will more then likely wind up maintaining that other app, it just *feels* counter productive to integrate a whole UCM/BPM solution into the guts of my application if I've already setup the Front-End and the DB back end.
(*Caveat:* My only experience with a CMS was [Plone](http://plone.org/), about 2 years ago and I *am not* a Python programmer.)

Comment: jbpm and drools are good, you could go for them!

Comment: You probably don't need a workflow engine, but go ahead, making mistakes is an important part of growing!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just use wicket auth roles. http://wicket.apache.org/learn/projects/authroles.html